# Hermite's equation of order $\alpha$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, power-series, summation

Show that the general solution of Hermite's equation of order $\alpha$:

$${y}''-2x{y}'+2\alpha y=0$$

$$is$$

$$y(x)=c_{0}y_{1}(x)+c_{1}y_{2}(x)$$

where $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ are power series solutions centered at the ordinary point 0.

Find the two power series.

I am stuck at this question. I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried to look for $y$ in the form of a power series around $0$, as suggested?

Comment: I am trying to show that the general solution is $y(x)=c_{0}y_{1}(x)+c_{1}y_{2}(x)$ where $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ are the power series but how can I do that?

Comment: Showing that two linearly independent solutions are given by power series is not the same as *finding* the solutions. What do you want exactly?

Comment: The question is asking me to show that the equation in my previous comment is the general solution then to find the power series $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$.

Comment: I edited my question, it is clear what I want now :)

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n}$. Substituting this into the equation, we find
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n}+2\alpha\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n}=0$$
or, equivalently,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n}+2\alpha\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n}=0.$$
This means that whenever 
$$a_{n+2}=\frac{2(n-\alpha)}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n,\tag{1}$$
the series will solve the differential equation. Obviously, $a_0$ and $a_1$ fix the rest of the series. In particular, we can set $a_1=0$ - then the series will contain only even powers of $x$. Similarly, for $a_0=0$ it will contain only odd powers of $x$. The general solution is an arbitrary linear combination of this odd and even part, so you can interpret $a_0$ and $a_1$ as two arbitrary integration constants.

---

**Added**: You can also explicitly solve the recursion (1): for example,
$$a_{2k}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac12)\Gamma(k-\frac{\alpha}{2})}{k!\Gamma(-\frac{\alpha}{2})\Gamma(k+\frac12)}a_0.$$
[Exercise: show this - for example, by induction]. Hence the series
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(\frac12)\Gamma(k-\frac{\alpha}{2})}{k!\Gamma(-\frac{\alpha}{2})\Gamma(k+\frac12)}x^{2k}$$
gives one solution of your differential equation.
One can similarly determine the coefficients with odd indices and write the second solution.

Comment: Too bad we can't "star" answers :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer is marvelous! I started learning differential equations today and I'm finding it very hard :(

Comment: This was not the simplest equation to start with :) I'd suggest first study methods of solutions of various 1st order equations and linear equations with constant coefficients. Here you have a special function equation.

Comment: Ok, I will learn basic DE first, thank you! By the way, I looked at your answers and they are very impressive :)